# Read sound output of computer in Node.js and analyze sound

Tags: node.js, npm, audio, node-modules

I can't find a Node.js npm package that allows me to record the current output of my mac's sound and lets me analyze it.

I'm trying to create a music visualizer that just shows the currently volume of sound playing from the computer.

Does anyone have tips or idea of what kinda of package to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 'node-audiorecorder' to capture time series audio data, as a WAV stream. -> [node-audiorecorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-audiorecorder)

This will basically give you float values that you could work with.
Some Example code of above,

```
// Import module.
const AudioRecorder = require('node-audiorecorder');
 
// Options is an optional parameter for the constructor call.
// If an option is not given the default value, as seen below, will be used.
const options = {
  program: `rec`,     // Which program to use, either `arecord`, `rec`, or `sox`.
  device: null,       // Recording device to use, e.g. `hw:1,0`
 
  bits: 16,           // Sample size. (only for `rec` and `sox`)
  channels: 1,        // Channel count.
  encoding: `signed-integer`,  // Encoding type. (only for `rec` and `sox`)
  format: `S16_LE`,   // Encoding type. (only for `arecord`)
  rate: 16000,        // Sample rate.
  type: `wav`,        // Format type.
 
  // Following options only available when using `rec` or `sox`.
  silence: 2,         // Duration of silence in seconds before it stops recording.
  thresholdStart: 0.5,  // Silence threshold to start recording.
  thresholdStop: 0.5,   // Silence threshold to stop recording.
  keepSilence: true   // Keep the silence in the recording.
};
// Optional parameter intended for debugging.
// The object has to implement a log and warn function.
const logger = console;
 
// Create an instance.
let audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(options, logger);
```

You could use the data you have captured and use [audio-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-render) For any analysis that you need to do. (The library has some functions to capture data itself)

```
myAudioStream
.pipe(Render(function (canvas) {
    var data = this.getFloatTimeDomainData();
 
    //draw volume, spectrum, spectrogram, waveform — any data you need
}))
.pipe(Speaker());
```

Comment: Hi @meth-munindradasa, will the above node-audiorecorder code capture audio from recording devices like microphone? Or can it also route system audio output and stream it? I believe that was the question?